# Find the applicant's current URl

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

I'm request for get url :

```
  public Uri GetAbsoluteUri()
    {
        var request = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Request;
        UriBuilder uriBuilder = new UriBuilder();
        uriBuilder.Scheme = request.Scheme;
        uriBuilder.Host = request.Host.Host;
        uriBuilder.Path = request.Path.ToString();
        uriBuilder.Query = request.QueryString.ToString();
        return uriBuilder.Uri;
    }

    public string RootPath => Path.Combine(WebRootPath, RootFolderName);

    public string GetProductPicturePath()
    {
        return Path.Combine(GetAbsoluteUri().ToString(), RootFolderName, ProductPictureFolder);
    }

    public string GetProductMainPicturePath()
    {
        string path = Path.Combine(GetAbsoluteUri().ToString(), RootFolderName, ProductPictureFolder, ProductMainPictureFolder);
        return path;
    }

    public string GetNewPath()
    {
        string productMainPicturePath = GetProductMainPicturePath();
        return Path.Combine(productMainPicturePath);
    }
```

> finally i using the `GetNewPath()`.

, but this will give me the address :

`https://localhost/api/Product/GetProductList/Upload/ProductPictureFolder/ProductMainPicture/77777.png`

but i have 2 problem with this url :

1 - it not contain port in url `https://localhost/api` but i need return like this : `http://localhost:4200/api`

2 - This includes the name of the controller and the ActionName, but I need to like this : `https://localhost/Upload/ProductPictureFolder/ProductMainPicture/77777.png`

but it return for me this : `https://localhost/api/Product/GetProductList/Upload/ProductPictureFolder/ProductMainPicture/77777.png`

i not need this `/api/Product/GetProductList` .

`Product :` Controller Name

`GetProductList :` ActionName

**How Can I Solve This Problem ???**

Comment: can you post exactly how you want your url to be.

Comment: @David i need this `https://localhost:44390/Upload/ProductPictureFolder/ProductMainPicture/77777.png`

Comment: @David it not working

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 1 - it not contain port in url https://localhost/api but i need return like this

To get port you can use this snippet :

```
if (request.Host.Port.HasValue) 
   uriBuilder.Port = request.Host.Port.Value;
```

> 2 - This includes the name of the controller and the ActionName, but I
>   need to like this :
>   https://localhost/Upload/ProductPictureFolder/ProductMainPicture/77777.png

I suggest you that set UriBuilder Path based on your needs, not from the request. Something like this:

```
// Make your Upload file path here
var relativePath = Path.Combine(folderName, filename);

var request = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Request;
var uriBuilder = new UriBuilder
{
    Host = request.Host.Host,
    Scheme = request.Scheme,
    Path = relativePath
};

if (request.Host.Port.HasValue) 
    uriBuilder.Port = request.Host.Port.Value;

var imageUrl = uriBuilder.ToString();
```